# CSS show four dropdown menu side by side. Link by jsfiddle is available

Tags: html, css

Im stuck on creating four dropdown menu side by side with a header on a pair of them. The result im trying to make should look like this

```
               Header                                                Header2
    [menu1]               [menu2]   [submit button]        [menu3]            [menu4]    [submit button]
```

But it looks like this for me right now:

```
Header [menu1] [menu2] [sub button]


Header1 [menu1] [menu2] [sub button]
```

This is what i have done so far, you can see it in JSFiddle link blew:

https://jsfiddle.net/snrk425x/

Answer (score 0):

Just change your info css class into flex. 
You can read about it here: [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).

```css
.info {
    display: flex; 
}

select {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">

  <form action="server.php" method="post" class="box">
        <select name="from"></select>
        <select name="to"></select>


  <button type="submit" name="valuta" onsubmit="update.style.display='none'">show graph </button>

  </form>
  
  <form action="server1.php" method="post" class="box">

        <select  name="from"></select>

        <select name="to"></select>


  <button id="cryp1" type="submit" name="cryp" onsubmit="update.style.display='none'"> show graph </button>

  </form>

  </div>
```